# JAVA: Integrate jar reference into Visual Studio Code "project"

Tags: java, eclipse, import, visual-studio-code

... previously I was using Eclipse to develop small java testing projects.
Now I will change to VSC. But I have a (simple) problem. (In this case GINMF.) ;-)
In Eclipse I could integrate external jar resources like testng.jar into the project (using the adding-to-build-path-function). After this step I could use them as an import-reference in the relevant java-class. But now this external resources wouldn't used/detected by VSC. Must I do some config steps before?
The jar's are located in a subfolder called "./libs/testng":

|- src
|- libs
..|- testng
.... |- testng.jar

Error message:
[Java] The import org.testng.* cannot be resolved
...
import org.testng.*;
...

Comment: In the .classpath (generated by Eclipse) I have this entry:
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.testng.TESTNG_CONTAINER"/>

Comment: Ok, I was solving the problem by adding this line to the .classpath file: <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/testng/testng.jar"/> ....  But maybe someone could explain to me why the "con"-entry is working in Eclipse but not in VSC??

Comment: The `.classpath` file is Eclipse specific. The `kind="con"` is in indirect reference via a specific _container_ variable that have to be specified elsewhere. It seems VCS understands only the basics of Eclipse's `.classpath` file format.

Comment: Ok and what is the best practice in VSC to add/link external jar resources?

Comment: Does `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/absolute/path/to/testng.jar"/>` work?

Comment: Yes, this is what I tried (see 2nd comment) and it works fine for me. But .classpath is a special eclipse conifguration part (or not?). I want to understand how I can link jar resources in a new/explicit VSC project.

Comment: In your 2nd comment you have a relative path but `kind="lib"` works also with an absolute path (starting with `/` or `C:/`).